# How can I import a variable from one script to another?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I constructed a certain automated WEB GUI test which was implemented by a python script (FireFox_FirstTests.py). In order to run this test repeatedly I have written another script (OSNR_Cycle.py) which is using an index variable "i" to count the number of cycles.
I want to be able to add this index "i" every cycle to the write to file. The result should be that the current line in the text file will show the current "i" value along with the current time&date with two measurements.

**OSNR_Cycle.py:**

```
import os

i = 0

while True:
    i = i +1
    os.system("FireFox_FirstTests.py")

    if i == 500:
       break
```

**FireFox_FirstTests.py:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import time
from OSNR_Cycle import i
from ReadWrite2File_Experiments import file

def Cold_Restart():

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    SysBtn = browser.find_element_by_id('System')
    SysBtn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('main_menu')
    Mainten_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('Maintenance')
    Mainten_Btn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    Mntn_Rst_Tab = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_restart')
    Mntn_Rst_Tab.click()

    browser.switch_to.frame('maint_sys')
    Cold_Rst_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('cold_restart')
    Cold_Rst_Btn.click()

    #In order to confirm the Alert Message I first need to switch to the     alert pop-up message and then accept it
   alertDialog = browser.switch_to_alert()
   alertDialog.accept()

   time.sleep(205)

   return

def Save_2_File(Rx_Pwr, OSNR_Lvl):
    file = open("test_results.txt", "a")
    file.write(i, '.')
    file.write(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y    ')) # Print Time & Date to the text file 
    file.write(Rx_Pwr) # Print the Rx_Pwr to the text file
    file.write('%10s' %(OSNR_Lvl)) # Format the placement of the OSNR value
    file.write('\n') # Make sure that the next iteration will write the results in the next line
    file.close() # Closing the file

    return



profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
browser.get('http://10.0.1.134')
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # Implicit wait


browser.maximize_window()

# Find the User Name text box and fill the User name
user_name_box = browser.find_element_by_id('u_name_box')
user_name_box.click()
user_name_box.send_keys('admin')

# Find the Password text box and fill the Password
user_pass_box = browser.find_element_by_id('u_pass_box')
user_pass_box.click()
user_pass_box.send_keys('admin')

login_button = browser.find_element_by_id('login_but')
login_button.click()


# Go to the Uplink 1 CFP2 information and take the Rx Pwr
browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
Port_19 = browser.find_element_by_id('Port-19')
Port_19.click()
browser.switch_to.default_content()

# Show the Optic Module information TAB
browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
CFP2_Info = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_XFP')
CFP2_Info.click()

# Collect the Rx Pwr from the CFP2 Info screen
browser.switch_to.frame('config_port') # Move to the inner frame that   holds all the tables
Rx_Pwr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]') # Take the Rx Pwr according to its Xpath
RcvPwr = Rx_Pwr.text

# Collect the OSNR measurement from the CFP2 Info screen
OSNR = browser.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
OSNR_Lvl = OSNR.text

Save_2_File(RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl)

Cold_Restart()

browser.quit()
```

My problem is that after the last change that I did, adding the "**from OSNR_Cycle import i**" I not only failed to get the needed result but I also got into situation that multiple python.exe process are started and the Memory is flooded.
What is the reason for the memory flood ?
How can I get the needed result (index printed to the file every cycle) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into your code i don't think you have to import variable from another code.There are two approaches to solve this question.

1) Simply Save your Local variable or Use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) from ONSR_cycle into file, and read the Pickle or file.

2) Second but Simple solution to this will be write your code of ONSR_cycle in the FireFox_FirstTests.py so that you can access it as local variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import time
from ReadWrite2File_Experiments import file

def main(): 
    i =0   
    while True:
        i = i +1
        #os.system("FireFox_FirstTests.py")
        execute_code(i)
        if i == 500:
           break

def Cold_Restart():

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    SysBtn = browser.find_element_by_id('System')
    SysBtn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('main_menu')
    Mainten_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('Maintenance')
    Mainten_Btn.click()

    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    Mntn_Rst_Tab = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_restart')
    Mntn_Rst_Tab.click()

    browser.switch_to.frame('maint_sys')
    Cold_Rst_Btn = browser.find_element_by_id('cold_restart')
    Cold_Rst_Btn.click()

    #In order to confirm the Alert Message I first need to switch to the     alert pop-up message and then accept it
   alertDialog = browser.switch_to_alert()
   alertDialog.accept()

   time.sleep(205)

   return

def Save_2_File(Rx_Pwr, OSNR_Lvl,i):
    file = open("test_results.txt", "a")
    file.write(i, '.')
    file.write(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y    ')) # Print Time & Date to the text file 
    file.write(Rx_Pwr) # Print the Rx_Pwr to the text file
    file.write('%10s' %(OSNR_Lvl)) # Format the placement of the OSNR value
    file.write('\n') # Make sure that the next iteration will write the results in the next line
    file.close() # Closing the file

    return


def execute_code(i):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
    browser.get('http://10.0.1.134')
    browser.implicitly_wait(10) # Implicit wait


    browser.maximize_window()

    # Find the User Name text box and fill the User name
    user_name_box = browser.find_element_by_id('u_name_box')
    user_name_box.click()
    user_name_box.send_keys('admin')

    # Find the Password text box and fill the Password
    user_pass_box = browser.find_element_by_id('u_pass_box')
    user_pass_box.click()
    user_pass_box.send_keys('admin')

    login_button = browser.find_element_by_id('login_but')
    login_button.click()


    # Go to the Uplink 1 CFP2 information and take the Rx Pwr
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    browser.switch_to.frame('box_menu')
    Port_19 = browser.find_element_by_id('Port-19')
    Port_19.click()
    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # Show the Optic Module information TAB
    browser.switch_to.frame('main_body')
    CFP2_Info = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_XFP')
    CFP2_Info.click()

    # Collect the Rx Pwr from the CFP2 Info screen
    browser.switch_to.frame('config_port') # Move to the inner frame that   holds all the tables
    Rx_Pwr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]') # Take the Rx Pwr according to its Xpath
    RcvPwr = Rx_Pwr.text

    # Collect the OSNR measurement from the CFP2 Info screen
    OSNR = browser.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/form/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
    OSNR_Lvl = OSNR.text

    Save_2_File(RcvPwr, OSNR_Lvl,i)

    Cold_Restart()

    browser.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have 2 problems with your solution: "i" inside main() is marked as undefined for some reason. and "browser" inside Cold_Restart() is also marked as undefined. Regarding browser I believe that it somehow relates to the fact that the execute_code() turned "browser" into a local variable (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I have just explained you the mechanism / workflow to resolve your problem. I don't have your dependency installed in my machine. So cant debug but by this way you can resolve your problem

Comment: I think that I solve the "browser" issue. One more variable needs to be handled. Don't I need to initialize "i" (i=0) ?

Comment: you can initialize i = 0 in main function

Comment: Thanks. That is what I exactly did and it solved the "i" definition issue